# Mann Whitney and boostrap confidence intervals provide contradictory results

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, bootstrap, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

We are doing some a/b testing and have non-normal metrics so our typical t-test aren't appropriate. I typically use bootstrap CI and/or Mann whitney tests to determine the true effect. In this case though, we are seeing very contradictory results – boostrap CI shows a p-value of 0.006 while MW p-value is 0.59. How can these be so different? Which is the more appropriate value?

Comment: A couple things to clarify: are the effect size estimates very different or just the p-values? What kind of bootstrapping are you doing? If parametric, then that could be the issue. What's the sample size? What kind of non-normality are you looking at with these measures? Non-normal data can be problematic, but if the sample size is big enough or the data "sufficiently normal", then the t-test becomes fairly robust.

Comment: @Billy Effect sizes are the same, just pvalues are different. I didn't write the code but given the differences, it's like a parametric bootstrap - that could be the big issue. Sample sizes are LARGE (millions) and I know the data is non-normal to the point that we need these types of non-parametric tests. It sounds like I'll need to review the code on the bootstrap...

Comment: Depending on your field, the effect size may be the thing that really matters here. It seems like both approaches are telling you the same thing with regard to size of the effect but differ in whether they think that effect could be observed due to chance alone. My preference would be just to report the confidence interval on the effect size and interpret that, but I also know that p-values are the standard reporting for most fields and journals. But, yeah, it sounds like the bootstrap method is maybe assuming a different type of distribution and thus giving different results.

Comment: With sample sizes in the millions, are you SURE you need anything other than a t-test (really a z-test at that sample size)?  T-tests compare sample means, and the sample mean with a sample size in the millions can be essentially normally distributed even with pretty remarkable deviances from normality for a single observation.

Answer (score -1):

If your sample size under 30 , I think the power of test student is lower and it will give biased results, the Mann-Whitney is recommended in that sens because it does not require that your data are normal or not. It is a nonparametric test.

Secondly, don't focus only on p-value; you have to compute the effect size because it will give more insight about the magnitude of this significance. This parameter is highly recommended when you report your results, especially in epidemiology and psychology.

The idea of bootstrap is also perfect it help you to ensure that results obtained are stable when you resample your data.

Here some useful references :

Efron, B. (1969). Student's t-test under symmetry conditions. Journal of the American Statistical Association, 64, 1278-1302.

Fisher, R. A. (1925). Applications of Student's distribution. Metron, 5, 90-104.

Hatch, L. 0. and Posten, H. O. (1967). "Robustness of the Student procedure. A survey. Research Report No. 24, Department of Statistics, University of Connecticut, Storrs, CT.

Hotelling, H., (1961). The behavior of some standard statistical tests under non-standard conditions. Proceedings of the Fourth Berkeley Symposium, 1, 319-360.